# Selenium webdriver- how to print google search result description on console

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Proble statement is as follows:
Open www.google.com in browser.
Add selenium hq in search
findout search result for wikipedia link for selenium hq.
print description which is displayed next to link to console.

search result is sometimes appears on 1st page and sometimes not.
i am able to search on 1st page and if its not there then traverse to 2nd page and so on.
but not able to get that description.
My code is:

```
    WebDriver driver = null;
    String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']")).sendKeys("Selenium HQ");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List<WebElement> linkElements = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        ListIterator<WebElement> itr = null;
        WebElement toClick = null;

        int pageNumber = 1;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        boolean flag = false;
        while (!flag) 
        {
            linkElements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                    .xpath("//h3[@class='s']")));
            itr = linkElements.listIterator(); // re-initializing iterator
            while (itr.hasNext()) 
            {
                toClick = itr.next();
                if (toClick.getText().contains("Wikidata")) 

                {
                    String desc = toClick.getText();
                    System.out.println(desc);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!flag) 
            {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']/span[1]")).click();
                pageNumber++;
                linkElements.clear(); // clean list
               // wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(
                        //By.xpath("//div[@class='st']"), pageNumber + ""));
            }
        }
        driver.close();
```

looking for a solution to this problem..

Comment: Can you get the description on console when the element is present on the first page?

Comment: Instead of `.xpath("//h3[@class='s']")))` is used selector `.xpath("//div[@class='s']")))`

Comment: i want to know how to get the description of an element on console. description is what is displayed below the link on google search result.also one more question is : as google search result is dynamic so how to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried with the change I suggested above? I tried it on my system and the specific Description with "Wikidata" was printed on the console.